# ipRestrictions not working in Grails 3.3.10?

Tags: grails, spring-security, ip-restrictions

I can't get ipRestrictions to work via springsecurity.
I'm working with a bare app to try and isolate the issue with Grails 3.3.10 and spring-security-core 3.2.0.

Eventually I want to restrict access to a web service to a limited subnet. But in an attempt to get this to work I'm just trying to find any case that will get rejected.

I'm working with a stock create-app application but I've added the following to build.gradle to pull in spring-security:

```
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0'
```

My application.groovy to configure this is:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ipRestrictions = [
    [pattern: '/**', access: '172.16.0.1']
]
```

I'm expecting to see something like a 401 Unauthorized or 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Are you working locally? [`All addresses can always be accessed from localhost regardless of IP pattern, primarily to support local development mode.`](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/3.2.x/index.html#ip)

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand it that way. Maybe it should say patterns. Well that actually makes it harder to test, but thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IP Address Restrictions](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/3.2.x/index.html#ip) don't apply to requests coming from `localhost`. This is to "help" local development but subsequently makes testing your restrictions more difficult. There is a confusingly worded note at the bottom of section 18 of the docs that should start "All patterns can always be accessed from localhost regardless of IP address":

> All addresses can always be accessed from localhost regardless of IP pattern, primarily to support local development mode.